# More efficient solution?

Tags: java

I just completed a question on Kattis "A Rational Sequence 2" and want to know if there is a more efficient way in which I can convert a binary number into decimal. This was my code:

```
public static int getDecimalValue(String sequence){

    int value = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); i++){
        if(sequence.charAt(i) == '1')
            value += (int)Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: This is Java by the way...

Comment: try this : Integer.parseInt(binaryString,2)

Comment: you could use Integer.parseInt(sequence, 2);...second argument is for the base of conversion for binary it is 2...

Comment: What you are actually doing here is to convert a string into a number. The number will (on most computers) still be in binary, because this is how computers represent numbers.

Comment: Btw. your solution is not correct. `value` should be initialized to 0 instead of 1 and you are processing the binary digits in reverse order.

Comment: `(int)Math.pow(2, i)` is equivalent to `1 << i`.

Comment: The code you posted converts an ASCII binary *string* to *binary*. There is no decimal in this question whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback! Also, did not realize I initiated  value to 1, so thank you for catching that! Somehow, the problem was still accepted...

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback! Also, did not realize I initiated  value to 1, so thank you for catching that! @Henry Somehow, the problem was still accepted...

Answer (score 0):

int value = Integer.parseInt(sequence, 2);

Comment: This is not what he asked for...

Comment: @bharath and why not? did you check the JRE code for efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points.  First, there's actually an error in your code - try passing it 00000000 (8 zeros) and see what happens.

As for efficiency, there's a couple of savings you could make.  You could change where you calculate the length and you could [bitshift](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) the calculation, which is quite a bit faster.

```
public static int getBinaryValue(String sequence){

    int value = 1; //have another glance at this line!

    for(int i = 0, n=sequence.length(); i < n; i++){
    //I declared a variable 'n' in the initialisation, this means its only 
    //checked once, rather than being checked every time
        if(sequence.charAt(i) == '1')
            value += 1 << i;
            //and here I've bitshifted the value.  Basically I've said "take 
            //the number one and then shift it left down an imaginary binary
            //track i times".  So if i is three, for example, it'll shift it
            //from 00000001 to 00000010 to 00000100 to 00001000, which is 8
            //2^3 = 8
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not too good with bit manipulation yet, so I will definitely play around with this, although, your explanation was very good! Appreciate it!